# Do something if one of the selected jQuery elements satisfy a condition

Tags: jquery

Is there a way to easily write a condition that result in true whenever one of the selected jQuery element satisfy a certain condition?

```
if($('input[name*="box_feature"]').attr('value') === undefined)) {

}
```

I have the above code, but the problem is that sometime we have more than one input with the same name and one of them can be defined. So what's the easiest way to do this in jQuery, that is, checking if at least one of the selected element meet a certain condition.

Comment: So you want to set all elements' attribute set to be true if certain condition is met?

Comment: Normally when I'm doing something like this I use if(typeof x =='undefined').  Combining this with a jquery .each loop would probably be what you need.  Loop through them all and if you get one which passes the test then set some flag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check multiple attributes in the selector:

```
if( $('input[name*="box_feature"][value]').length > 0 ) {
    alert('found');
}
```

References:

- http://api.jquery.com/has-attribute-selector/
- http://api.jquery.com/multiple-attribute-selector/